# how to enable microsoft edge accessibility

Tags: accessibility, microsoft-edge, narrator

I have problem with edge accessibility on window 10.

I see that microsoft edge supported accessibility technology as narrator. It can access and read controls on window 10. I try and see that it works normally.
However, AccExplore32 tool can not access web element in Edge although it still works with IE.

I use accessibility technology like AccTool. Therefore, I can not access control in Edge page.

Chrome has a setting that force chrome enable accessiblity by "--force-renderer-accessibility"

Does Edge have it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the accessibility tree of Microsoft Edge using Inspect.exe from the Windows 10 SDK. You'll get the most accurate representation if you choose "UI Automation Mode" and "Control View" from the Options menu in Inspect.

Please see this blog post for more information on accessibility in Edge: [Accessibility: Towards a more inclusive web with Microsoft Edge and Windows 10](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/09/25/accessibility-towards-a-more-inclusive-web-with-microsoft-edge-and-windows-10/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Inspect and UIA Verify tools still detect control. However, it use UIA technology to access.

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're asking about MSAA support in Edge?

Comment: While IE had an MSAA implementation, with UIA Express added to support more advanced accessibility features, Edge has a full UIA implementation. MSAA is not able to express many modern UI constructs, including much of HTML5 and ARIA. Windows does provide a bridge so that MSAA-based AT can get information out of UIA-based applications. However, not everything can be translated. If you point an MSAA-based tool at Edge, some web content elements may not be available.

Comment: I have read the blog post. Mic transport MSAA to UIA technology.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (November 19th, 2015) Microsoft still doesn't provide *fair* accessibility in `ApplicationFrame.dll` which powers Edge, Calendar, the built-in mail client and some other Windows 10 apps. They actually broke the UIA (User Interface Automation) for assistive technologies.
This exactly is the reason why JAWS for Windows and other great assistive technology players lack support for Edge and other apps based on this library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
May be it does not support accessibility like Acc tool